# Could not allocate JNI Env

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm updating my API every 2seconds,
but I am receiving this error and my application closes.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: com.application.toweeloasep, PID: 6681
>                                                                              java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Could not allocate JNI Env
>                                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:730)
>                                                                                  at com.android.volley.RequestQueue.start(RequestQueue.java:145)
>                                                                                  at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:66)
>                                                                                  at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:78)
>                                                                                  at com.application.toweeloasep.fragments.Jobs$5$1.run(Jobs.java:260)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

After about a minute, it starts to crash and receives that error.
Am I overdoing things with Volley?

```
private void setRepeatingAsyncTask() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            if (checkRequests) {
                                RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
                                StringRequest mStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://api.000.com/booking/track", new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                                        Log.e("RESPONSE:TRACK", response);
                                        try {
                                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                                            String mStatus = json.getString("status");
                                            if (mStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                                                Log.e("STATUS", mStatus);
                                            } else if (mStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                                                JSONArray infos = json.getJSONArray("data");
                                                booking_id = infos.getJSONObject(0).getString("id");
                                                user_address_location = infos.getJSONObject(0).getString("user_address_location");
                                                mTxtBatteryInfo.setText(infos.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("battery").getString("model"));
                                                mTxtUserLocation.setText(user_address_location);
                                                checkRequests = false;
                                                mJobsHome.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                mJobRequest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                if (!onTick) {
                                                    mCountDownTimer.start();
                                                    onTick = true;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            Log.e("ERR", e.toString());
                                        }
                                    }
                                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                        Log.e("ERR", error.toString());
                                    }
                                });
                                mRequestQueue.add(mStringRequest);
                            } else {
                                RequestQueue requestPlaceInfo = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
                                StringRequest request2 = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://api.000.com/booking/track", new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                                        Log.e("RESPONSE", response);
                                    }
                                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }) {
                                    @Override
                                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                                        params.put("booking_id", booking_id);
                                        params.put("rider_long", String.valueOf(lng));
                                        params.put("rider_lat", String.valueOf(lat));
                                        return params;
                                    }
                                };
                                requestPlaceInfo.add(request2);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // error, do something
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(task, 0, 2000);  // interval of one minute
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> OutOfMemoryError ... at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue

Why do you need to create a new RequestQueue or StringRequest every two seconds?

Try making only one of each.

```
private final Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e("ERR", String.valueOf(error));
    }
};

private void setRepeatingVolleyTask() {
    final RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

    final StringRequest trackRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://api.toweelo.com/booking/track", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("RESPONSE:TRACK", response);
            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                String mStatus = json.getString("status");
                if (mStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                    Log.d("STATUS", mStatus);
                } else if (mStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                    JSONArray infos = json.getJSONArray("data");
                    booking_id = infos.getJSONObject(0).getString("id");
                    user_address_location = infos.getJSONObject(0).getString("user_address_location");
                    mTxtBatteryInfo.setText(infos.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("battery").getString("model"));
                    mTxtUserLocation.setText(user_address_location);
                    checkRequests = false;
                    mJobsHome.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mJobRequest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (!onTick) {
                        mCountDownTimer.start();
                        onTick = true;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERR", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }, errorListener );

    final StringRequest trackRequest2 = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://api.toweelo.com/booking/track", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("RESPONSE", response);
        }
    }, errorListener) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("booking_id", booking_id);
            params.put("rider_long", String.valueOf(lng));
            params.put("rider_lat", String.valueOf(lat));
            return params;
        }
    };

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // What are you trying to catch here??
                    try {
                        if (checkRequests) {
                            mRequestQueue.add(trackRequest);
                        } else {
                             mRequestQueue.add(trackRequest2);
                    } catch ( ... ) {
                        ....
                    }
```

Note: You can use `JsonObjectRequest` instead of parsing JSON from a StringRequest

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll get back here if it worked. THanks

Comment: It worked I think. I idle the app and nothing appened. 
FF question, what's the benefit of using Jsobjectrquest instead of string request?

Comment: The benefit is that you are requesting JSON, so you don't need to do `JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);` yourself. And if you read the Volley documentation, you could use Gson to create your own JSON request parser which would immediately return Java objects without you having to parse the data yourself. Retrofit is another option